# Upload image and text data in iphone

Tags: ipad, ios4, iphone

Hi stackoverflow friends

I want to upload text along with image to the webserver. I saw so many examples for uploading images to webserver but nobody explains how to send text from a uitextField along with image.
All of them points this link

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/

This link gives only how to upload images only. I want to send some text values along with this. Could you please send me some example code.

Any help is Appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you try `ASIHTTPRequest`. It allows you to easily accomplish such a task. You can create a PHP file that will receive your data via `POST` - `ASIHTTPRequest` provides some easy to use methods for this.

See [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Comment: hi David Schiefer thanks for your quick response. could you give me a sample code for this?

Comment: Hi David Schiefer thank u so much. It really helpful for  me.

Answer (score 1):

you can Use [Evernote API](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/ios.php) for this purpose